# How to include licenses for packages downloaded with Nuget?

Tags: licensing

I have a software that uses some MIT and Apache licenses.
The source code is not open source and all the third-party software is downloaded from Nuget as a reference (I'm not including the source code in my project or modyfing it).
Do I have to include some license information somewhere in my project or documentation?

It might seem as a trivial question, but I'm looking for direct answer for an hour now without success.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't store the code bin your repository, then you don't need to have a specific mention of the license of those dependencies.

However, when you distribute a binary that contains (compiled) code of those dependencies, then you must must mention those dependencies and their licenses either in the documentation that comes with the binary or in a screen with licensing information that is part of the binary.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet's official docs have [this section on including a license expression or file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-a-license-expression-or-a-license-file), if you're packing an SDK style project. License expression won't work for you, because I believe only open source licenses are included in the SPDX specification.

Basically, in your project file, you'll need a property which tells NuGet what the path to the license file will be once packed, and an item to tell NuGet which file on disk to put in the package.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE.txt</PackageLicenseFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="licenses\LICENSE.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath=""/>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you're still using a nuspec file, [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#license) explains how to do it.